# Store random numbers in a text file (Java)

Tags: java

I have made a code that creates 10 random numbers, I want to store these numbers in a text file but it only stores the last number 10 times, how do I fix this? I'm very new into coding, thanks in advance!

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class Dices
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        Random ran = new Random();
        int number = 0;

        for (int x = 0; x <10; x++) {
            number = ran.nextInt(6)+1;
            //System.out.println(number);

        }



            try (PrintWriter file = new PrintWriter(
                    new BufferedWriter(
                            new FileWriter("test1.txt")));
            ) {

                for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
                    file.println(number);
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            System.out.println("File test1.txt has been created!");


        }
    }
```

Comment: Do `number = ran.nextInt(6)+1;` on the line *immediately before* the line `file.println(number);`

Answer (score 1):

Remove the first loop and move the radomization code to the second loop to appear as:

```java
package com.vinrithi.main;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class Dices {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random ran = new Random();
        int number = 0;
        try (PrintWriter file = new PrintWriter(
                new BufferedWriter(
                        new FileWriter("test1.txt")));
        ) {

            for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
                number = ran.nextInt(6) + 1;
                file.println(number);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("File test1.txt has been created!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you are creating ten random values, but you never use the 9 first ones, because you first compute the random values, and afterwards you add the variable ten times to your file. A Variable can not have 10 different values ! You must write your number every time you randomize it. So :

```java
for (int x = 0; x < 10; i++) {
     int number = ran.nextInt(6) + 1;
     try(PrintWriter file = new PrintWritter(new BufferedWritter(new FileWritter("test1.txt")));) {
        file.println(number);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there. The problem was your file.println(number) line that was not in the right loop. Indeed, if I read your code you are first giving a random integer to the number variable 10 times and once it's done, you create a new file called test1.txt and write in there what's in your number variable 10 times. That's why the same integer appears 10 times in your file.
This way should work :

public class Dices {

```
public static void main( String[] args ) {
    Random ran = new Random();
    int number = 0;

    try {
        PrintWriter file = new PrintWriter(
            new BufferedWriter(
                    new FileWriter("test1.txt")));


        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            number = ran.nextInt(6) + 1;
            file.println(number);
        }
        file.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("File test1.txt has been created!");
}
```

}